# How to create a triangular background with CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have following html block

```
<div class=""header>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <h1>some text goes here</h1>
</div>
```

and these css styles

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px 0 0 200px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;

}
```

and also i am using fontawesome icon fonts. What i am trying to achieve is this[image]

This is what i have tried [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vudmw/2/) . i completely failed to do this. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You're half way there, and +1 for a very well made question

Comment: crazy fiddle, i like it :)

Comment: Your JS Fiddle links font-awesome JS library files incorrectly.

Comment: Great question, well structured.  Have you look at border radius (css3)?

Comment: @Myles yes but i dont understand how to use bordr radius with this.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I was able to achieve this with css Pseudo-elements

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

> A CSS pseudo-element is a keyword added to a selector that lets you style a specific part of the selected element(s). For example, ::first-line can be used to change the font of the first line of a paragraph.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  margin: -130px 0 0 200px;
}

i {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 0 0 200px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
}

i:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\F005";
  font-size: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="" header>
  <i></i>
  <h1>some text goes here</h1>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vudmw/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

you have used h1 in your html and h2 in your css!

this may help

```
h1 {
    margin: -130px 0 0 200px;
}
i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px 0 0 200px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vudmw/4/)

Comment: Thank you :). i updated the question and the jsfiddle. but the issue still remains .

Comment: did you try my answer?!

Comment: i have fiddle link in the answer!remove these two lines     display: inline-block;
    height:150px;

Answer (score 1):

This [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vudmw/9/) might get you a little closer. Please note that this requires your triangle to have a fixed height, so I could use a line-height:

```
#text {
float: right;
line-height: 200px;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 150px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
```

Do you want to create the star in the triangle using CSS as well?

Comment: No.. i use iconfonts for that.. thanks a lot for your answer..i found a way to do that

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to mark it as 'answer' if it was correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

LIke this

give `line-height` or `position:absolute;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sg2uG/)**

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
   line-height:150px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you guys think of this solution? http://jsfiddle.net/XrAaP/

Here's the HTML. (Proper HTML. Unlike using the italic tag for other things...)

```
<header>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="foreground">
        <h1>Some text goes here</h1>
        <p>*</p>
    </div>
</header>
```

And here's the CSS.

```
.triangle{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px 0 0 200px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.foreground{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

h1{
    margin-left: -128px;
}

p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 8em;
    margin: 0 0 0 -178px;
}
```